# Where Do I go to edit site content logo on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-logo, site-contents

I would like to know where I go to edit site content logo on sharepoint online. it is online aff
[image]

Comment: Hope this can help you out URL: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-your-SharePoint-team-site-settings-8376034d-d0c7-446e-9178-6ab51c58df42

Answer (score 1):

For classic team sites, the menu to change the team site logo should be located in Site Settings > Title, Description, and logo.

[image]

If the site is created as part of an Office 365 Group, it is a modern team site.  It is not feasible to change the logo of the site in this scenario. The team site's picture will follow the group's picture.
To change your group's picture, you can navigate to your group's Conversation tab and click the group's picture to replace it.

Comment: it still don't change image on site content logo.